# Commands in Dockerfile and commands in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using the [jonasal/nginx-certbot:latest](https://github.com/jonasalfredsson/docker-nginx-certbot) to run several services under NGINX with automatic certificate generation.

I now want to create a second instance for UAT testing where all domains shift from `[subdomain].domain.com` to `[subdomain]-uat.domain.com`. To enable this I have substituted the domains by environment variables and used the following command in the `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
    command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/user_conf.d/ssl-server.conf.template > /etc/nginx/user_conf.d/ssl-server.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

This produces the correct `ssl_server.conf` file but does not seem to start the `certbot` process.

I'm trying to figure out if using a command in the `docker-compose.yaml` overrules the `RUN` command in the Dockerfile but cannot find anything to say that.

I'm also trying to trigger the run command from within the `docker-compose.yaml` file like.

```
    command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/user_conf.d/ssl-server.conf.template > /etc/nginx/user_conf.d/ssl-server.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;' && /scripts/start_nginx_certbot.sh"
```

But this does not make a difference.

What am I missing?

Comment: A Docker container only runs one process; do you need a second container for certbot?  Also see the section "Using environment variables in nginx configuration" in the [Docker Hub `nginx` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx); you shouldn't need to run `envsubst` yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command overrides the command in the image, so you need to run the startup script yourself as you show in your last command.

I think your error in that is that you also run nginx. When you do it that way, your 'base' nginx starts and since it doesn't exit, the normal startup script is never run. Try this

```
command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/user_conf.d/ssl-server.conf.template > /etc/nginx/user_conf.d/ssl-server.conf && /scripts/start_nginx_certbot.sh"
```